# How to use data object to upload data into AWS Athena table via javascript

Tags: amazon-athena

I'd like to upload data into an Athena table using javascript.

As this document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/athena/command/StartQueryExecutionCommand/),
I should use query string.

Can I upload the data as an object itself without creating query string?

For example, in BigQuery, it is possible. (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js)